# How to resolve the error: SQL authentication method unknown in Laravel-MySql

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, laravel-5.5, mysql-8.0

I using docker and I have a container of Laravel Framework 5.5.25 and other with mysql  Ver 8.0.11 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL). in my configuration of docker compose I have this:

```
version: "2"
services:
    mysql:
    image: mysql
        ports:
            - "3307:3306"
        command: --sql_mode=""
```

So, when Laravel try to connect to MySql I have this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select * from

Comment: At the moment I had to go back to version 5.6 of MySql. but if someone knows how to solve the problem in version 8.0 welcome be. Thank you.

Comment: Check my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615936/6312647 For Ubuntu

Answer (score 21):

You have to use legacy style passwords for MySQL 8 and PHP7+:

```
ALTER USER 'username'@'ip_address' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Comment: guys be careful, this command might damage your mysql login process and gets `Access denied for user 'username'@'ip_address' ` that have to stop mysql and use mysql in safe mode to reset your password

Answer (score 16):

For local development using Laravel Valet I was able to resolve this using TablePlus SQL Query editor by typing this

`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypassword';`

I hope it helps someone too.

Answer (score 6):

I am using laravel 5.8 and having MAMP server got this error resolved by adding `DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock` in .env file like below

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

As I found in few of the blogs it generally comes because of the socket issue with latest MySQL version

Comment: For unix, this would be `DB_SOCKET=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`. This is definitely the cleanest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a Laravel way just simple edit  `config/database.php`

and add `modes` array to MySQL section:

```
 'connections' => [

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'      => 'mysql',
            'host'        => env( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1' ),
            'port'        => env( 'DB_PORT', '3306' ),
            'database'    => env( 'DB_DATABASE', 'forge' ),
            'username'    => env( 'DB_USERNAME', 'forge' ),
            'password'    => env( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' ),
            'unix_socket' => env( 'DB_SOCKET', '' ),
            'charset'     => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation'   => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'      => '',
            'strict'      => true,
            'engine'      => null,
            'modes'       => [
                'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
                'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
                'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
                'NO_ZERO_DATE',
                'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
                'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: +1 I'm using shared hosting: and this solution worked for me. Just add modes and clear the cache, and then it works!

Answer (score 0):

Reference : https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1392#issuecomment-368308494

1. Add default authentication plugin to /etc/mysql/my.cnf

   ```
   [mysqld]
   default_authentication_plugin= mysql_native_password
   ```
2. Login to `mysql` for create new user as follow,

   ```
   CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourpass';
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
   CREATE USER 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourpass';
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
   #
   CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `yourdb` COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' ;
   GRANT ALL ON `yourdb`.* TO 'admin'@'%' ;
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;
   ```

Note : Remove old user, database and recreate again by above script.