# Laravel/Lumen : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Tags: mysql, laravel, authentication, lumen

I uploade my Laravel/Lumen api to server after I checked it on localhost.
for any query I have using (Where) it gives me same error such as this:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select * from `seasons` where `status` = active limit 1)
```

for example the above error get from this line as postman mentioned :

```
$season = Season::where('status','active')->first();
```

if I have simple return Like :

```
$router->get('/',function (){
        return "welcome";
    });
```

it is return successfully ,How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you check the credentials of your database in `.env`?

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50547724/how-to-resolve-the-error-sql-authentication-method-unknown-in-laravel-mysql

Comment: @Milad yes i did and will check it again

Comment: @Milad thanks yes it was .env file mistake , I forgot replace root username

Comment: @Milad you can put answer to accept it

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. I don't think it's necessary to add an answer. Keep developing :)